# URL based on locale

Tags: symfony

Is it possible to change URL when locale is changed?
This is my route:

```
contact:
    path:     /{type}
    defaults: { _controller: WebPortalBundle:Default:contact }
    requirements:
        type: kontakty|contact
```

Is it possible when locale is "en" to display url with **type = contact**, when russian, czech, slovak, display with **type = kontaky** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. We are using https://github.com/BeSimple/BeSimpleI18nRoutingBundle that bundle for doing that.

After installation bundle you need to open config.yml file and add this config.

```
be_simple_i18n_routing: ~
```

After that open your main routing.yml file(app/routing.yml) and simply add type "be_simple_i18n". It's shoud be like that.

```
acme:
    resource: "@AcmeBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
    type: be_simple_i18n
```

And finally open bundle spesific routing.yml file (in that case AcmeBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml).

```
acme_contact:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeBundle:Default:contact }
    locales:  { en: "/contact", ru: "/kontaky" }
```

Comment: Could you add an example (or more) to complete your answer?

Comment: Right, now its much better :)

Comment: @kironet We are using that bundle on Symfony 2.8. But i just check it on latest symfony version but unfortunately it's not compile with Symfony 3 :(

Comment: Ahh, bundle looks nice, pity it's not compatible with symfony3 :(